# Create po-files from postgresql data

Tags: postgresql

My intention is to store and manage multiple languages in postgresql. And then create .po files directly from postgresql.

```
CREATE TABLE lang (
  msgid text primary key, 
  de text, 
  es text
);

INSERT INTO lang VALUES
('task','Aufgabe','tarea'),
('subject','Thema','sujeto'),
('description','Beschreibung','Descripción');
```

This query is my attempt

```
select msgid, de msgstr from lang
```

Which gives this result

[image]

The desired output should be a de.po file for direct use in translations from English to German

```
msgid "task"
msgstr "Aufgabe"

msgid "subject"
msgstr "Thema"

msgid "description"
msgstr "Beshreibung"
```

Fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eaQG8H4yqY9hnQBZjzJgz/134

Is this possible using Postgresql?

**EDIT**

A bit closer, but this does not work full on any tested fiddle or pg Admin.

```
SELECT format(E'msgid "%s"\nmsgstr "%s"\n', msgid, de) AS line
FROM lang;
```

Better suggestion?

Comment: This would something best done in a client program that could format the data and output it to a file .

Comment: What is a ".po file"?

Comment: @Bergi, a translation file per [PO](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html) file.